# Error when installing shap - asking for CUDA while I'm in AMD instead of NVIDIA

Tags: python, shap

Can anyone please help?

`pip install shap` doesn't work for me

```
The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. Either  add it to your path, or set $CUDAHOME to enable CUDA
    Error building cuda module: TypeError('cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object')
    WARNING: Could not compile cuda extensions
```

I can't have CUDA because I am using AMD in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1777 eg. Most probably it concerns not having right gcc in path